# Calculus book for basic calculus and repetition from videregående (Norwegian high school)

Tags: undergraduate-education, textbooks

Does there exist a textbook in Norwegian (bokmål and nynorsk should both be fine) that covers the more advanced mathematics (needed for calculus) from videregående (secondary school, includes both gymnasium and vocational lines), as well as basic calculus up to the level of integration and differentiation of functions in one dimension?

We are currently using Claudia Neuhauser's 'Calculus for biology and medicine', which has the significant flaw of being in English. Also, it does not cover the basics very well. The style is very verbose.

The course this is for is targeted for students of biology, geology, chemistry, etc. Many have very weak mathematics background; they have not taken the more advanced mathematics courses in videregående. I presume the additional cognitive load from using a book in a foreign language does not help matters.

A book written in Danish or Swedish might also help.

Comment: You are most likely the only Norwegian speaker on matheducators.SE, so we may not be able to make specific recommendations. One possibility would be to pick an open-source calculus text and translate it yourself into Norwegian. Some free texts are catalogued here: http://www.theassayer.org/cgi-bin/asbrowsesubject.cgi?class=Q#freeclassQAmg

Comment: @BenCrowell I am aware, but hard questions are fine on SE sites. My language skills are not good enough for translation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult for us to research it for you.  But you presumably have access to Norwegian libraries colleagues booksellers and know the language.  I would try to research it yourself.

One other idea for how to skin the cat is just to pick a less verbose English text.  Maybe Schaums Outline.

Edit.   Reading your question again it sounds like they could use some precalc also.  Frank Ayres first year college math is a good schaums for a review of all precalc and has a very simple intro to calc also.  If you did that plus the regular schaums calc they would be covered. Price is probably twenty for each. So cheaper than most standard texts overall.

And the students will love you because schaums is written to help students learn.  Not to impress professors.

Sorry for typos.  On my phone.

Comment: Yes, I'll probably self-answer at some point. But note that the entire purpose of this website is that since someone has done the research, others have less need to repeat it.

The answer would be improved by writing a bit more about Schaum's outline.

Comment: Schaums is an example.  The point I'm making is that you have a multifactor issue. Because the English text is verbose is not a strong reason to go Norwegian. In an ideal world of course you want ideal level, nurse focus, language, and verbosity.  But they are different factors.  Half a loaf...

Comment: What do you mean by "Frank Ayres first year college math is a good schaums for a review of all precalc"

Comment: Author, title, comment about book.   Sorry for typos.